# Azure functions : Failure Exception: Error: unsupported locale setting Stack

Tags: python, azure-functions

At some point in my code I set the locale :

```
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8")
```

When I run this code in azure-functions I get the following error :

```
Result: Failure Exception: Error: unsupported locale setting
```

How can I configure the azure function to support the locale I want to use?